# What is the simplest way to delete a corrupt registry key?

Tags: windows-registry, keys

I have a registry key that produces an error when selected in regedit. It may have multiple but unknown subkeys. regeidt isn't up to the task what is the best way to wipe out this key and anything within it?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't feel up to hacking together a script [Sysinternals RegDelNull](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897448.aspx) is another option for deleting "difficult" registry keys. And as ever, handle with care, like anything that messes directly with the registry it's a loaded gun and it can do a lot of damage.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is explained in this "[Hey, Scripting Guy!](http://207.46.16.252/en-us/magazine/2006.08.scriptingguy.aspx)" article.